# How to create a new Tag group and save it?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I'm new to the Craft CMS framework and have a question about tags. How can I create a new tag group?

You can create a tag list by hand via the admin panel > settings > Tag Groups > New Tag Group.
This is a way I can't use for plug-in development. So far as I know, I have to use the following code:

```
    $tagGroup = new TagGroup();
    $tagGroup->name = 'GroupName';
    $tagGroup->handle = 'GroupHandle';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. To save things in Craft, you need to use the according service. In your case you need the tags service:

```php
$tagGroup = new TagGroup();
$tagGroup->name = 'GroupName';
$tagGroup->handle = 'GroupHandle';
$isTagGroupSaved = Craft::$app->getTags()->saveTagGroup($tagGroup);

if(!$isTagGroupSaved) {
    // Inspect validation errors if saving the tag group failed
    var_dump($tagGroup->getErrors());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem :D